# Update array value PHP with variable index

Tags: php, arrays, variables, indexing

I have the following code:

```
$woo_options = get_option( 'woo_options' ); 
//print_r($woo_options);
$has_updated = false; 

foreach ($options as $value) {
//print_r($value);
update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ); 
    $key = $value['id'];
    $keyconf = $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ];

    **echo $woo_options[$key];**

    if ( isset( $woo_options[$key] ) ) {
        $woo_options[$key] = $keyconf;
        $has_updated = true;
        }
}       

if ( $has_updated == true ) {
update_option( 'woo_options', $woo_options );
}
```

The thing is if I put **echo $woo_options[$key];** nothing happens, and with **echo $woo_options['woo_author'];** with proper quotes, the value shows up... I need this to update a value from an array.

Here's a part of my "print_r($woo_options);"

Array ( [woo_alt_stylesheet] => [woo_logo] => [woo_texttitle] => [woo_font_site_title] => Array ( [size] => 40 [unit] => px [face] => Droid Serif [style] => 300 [color] => #ffffff ) 
[woo_google_analytics] => [ woo_feed_url] =>  [woo_subscribe_email] => 
 [woo_comments] => post  [woo_post_content] => excerpt  [woo_author] => false...

**Note: The $key var is showing up: woo_alt_stylesheet, woo_logo, woo_texttitle... as wanted...**

Comment: How about $woo_options[''.$key.''];, what does happen then? (isn't a real solution)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it using a function to compare two arrays and then update the "different" indexes... more info, contact me.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you trim your $key value?

```
$key = trim($value['id']);
```